# Gmaps results only local even when i query another city

Tags: python, function, google-places-api, jsonresult

I made a python program that takes a business type and location then outputs results in that location. The output is always local in the twin cities.

```py
def get_places(query, location):
    parameters = {"query": query, "location": location, "key": GOOGLE_API_KEY}

    all_results = []
    response = requests.get(ENDPOINT, params=parameters)
    results = response.json().get("results", [])
    all_results.extend(results)
```

results print confirming it should be searching tacoma WA but instead the results I keep getting minneapolis where I live: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=food&location=tacoma%2C+WA&key=xxxxxxxxxKEYxxxxxxxxxx&pagetoken=AUacShjNDU-_ibehFFVXMZseXVaF3h2S6P4DAXaIwWpJHgPuDvcCF95vgMiYjBmPiQOtiEcJvmLuFNWuoQBWEw1RYH8FKlPi7h4-jUsq2oYdpeEsoT00YojkdA7GofRggFd9KMCoRM_r-lyXnD7P4ZD6ylkeM029ycQ-9v6jdt6qobrmIq3Y6gikuRxOxHINMaFpnu-EMK5JvGkX46L_tEqz_dbur-rio4ivQPLvygqKcAjMfdMFrQWPsGzKMC7FtTVTCpwoGKKlEOIAr4cxNHtzGBgjTkUH4idJNKlCWpS1NJi15s-J40A1wJ0Wg5oFGV3OrCh5rUHR_ym28B98w8dnrMxibECfdljveS89MWJRR7BxIrQeLSYheNgu-_-_T0rmFNA

clearing cache and cookies didnt help either. The only thing that makes sense to me is a setting in my Cloud Console but I can't find anything that could be causing this.

Answer (score 0):

The docs for the location parameter say that it must be specified as a latitude/longitude pair:

> location
>
> The point around which to retrieve place information. This must be specified as `latitude,longitude`.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search-text#location

You'll need to [geocode](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/overview) your location before using it in a query.

Answer (score 0):

### Either use a `location` parameter specifying `latlng` or explicitly put the location in the `query` parameter.

You can't use an address name in the `location` parameter. What you should use is a `latlng` coordinate as mentioned in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search-text#location):

> *"...This must be specified as latitude,longitude."*

I tried to geocode the location you specified (Tacoma WA) which is around `47.25248908430412, -122.44652831940736`. So your query should look something like this:

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=food&location=47.25248908430412,%20-122.44652831940736&key=API_KEY`

The other way to do this is to explicitly mention the location in the query parameter itself. A note under the `location` parameter description in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search-text#location:%7E:text=The%20location%20parameter%20may%20be%20overriden%20if%20the%20query%20contains%20an%20explicit%20location%20such%20as%20Market%20in%20Barcelona.%20Using%20quotes%20around%20the%20query%20may%20also%20influence%20the%20weight%20given%20to%20the%20location%20and%20radius.) also says this:

> "*The **location** parameter may be overriden if the **query** contains an explicit location such as **Market in Barcelona**. Using quotes around the query may also influence the weight given to the **location** and **radius**.*"

This means that instead of including a `latlng` `location` parameter, you can just put the "Tacoma WA" inside the `query` parameter together with the string "food". Your query should look like this:

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=food%20in%20Tacoma%20WA&key=API_KEY`

This should provide you the expected results instead of the local foods in your area.

The most probable reason for this is because the `location` value you used is invalid, it searched for "foods" using your current location instead.

I hope this helps!